# Can someone check my algorithm for getting the mode of an array, with the tiebreaker being no mode at all?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

So, "diffs" is an array, such as [1, 1, 2, 2], or [1, 2, 4, 4]. "count" would be a histogram essentially, where the value at each index is the amount of times that index appears in "diffs". So, the histogram for the first example would be [0, 2, 2] (The size of the histogram is 1 + the max to account for index 0).

I run through "count" after it has been initialized properly, by working backwards and updating the mode. If the currently evaluated element in "count" is equal to the mode, then the mode is set back to -1, meaning no mode. This works for the small test cases I have, but for the larger ones I'm not sure if there's a lapse in judgment here.

```
        int mode = -1;
        if (diffs.size() != 0) {
            int[] count = new int[Collections.max(diffs) + 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < diffs.size(); j++) {
                count[diffs.get(j)]++;
            }
            int index = count.length - 1;
            for (int j = count.length - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (count[j] > count[index]) {
                    if (count[j] == count[index]) {
                        mode = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                    index = j;
                    mode = j;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Logic is a bit flawed as explained in the below answer. You may also want to check for cases where the `max` could be pretty huge, like `[1,2147483647,2147483647]` which would run out of heap space.

Comment: How might I account for those cases? Just change the arrays to hold longs instead?

Comment: Use a HashMap to store integers with their frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you set the mode to -1 if you find two count elements with the same value. The description of the problem I read [here](http://codinghelmet.com/exercises/array-mode) says the mode is

> the number that appears more times in the array than any other number

and

> If there are multiple solutions, i.e. two or more most frequent numbers occur equally many times, **function should return any of them**.

Even if you are required to return -1 in case of multiple solutions, your logic is wrong, because you only check `count[j] == count[index]` inside `if (count[j] > count[index])`, so it will never be true. Besides, even if you checked it outside that condition, breaking out of the loop is wrong, because there may still be a number that appears more times.

You probably want something like this:

```
    int mode = -1;
    if (diffs.size() != 0) {
        int[] count = new int[Collections.max(diffs) + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < diffs.size(); j++) {
            count[diffs.get(j)]++;
        }
        int index = count.length - 1;
        for (int j = count.length - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (count[j] > count[index]) {
                index = j;
                mode = j;
            } else if (count[j] == count[index]) {
                mode = -1;
                // don't break, since we may still find j such that count[j] > count[index]
            }
        }
    }
```